# How to convert a object into a Array but object is a IList

Tags: c#

```
public void ReadData(object Ob) {
 if(Ob.GetType().IsGenericType && Ob is IList) {
      // what I tested
      IList theList = (IList)Ob;
      Console.WriteLine(theList.ToArray()); // compiler error `IList` has not a method called ToArray
  }
}
```

how can I convert the `object` to a array. when the object is a `IList`

Comment: add `using System.Linq`

Comment: already added same compiler issue

Comment: You can use this as well: `((IList)Ob).Cast<object>().ToArray()` but it helps if you know the type of item in the list, then you could cast directly to (ex) `IList<int>`

Comment: thanxs for help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you can do this instead:

```
public void ReadData(object Ob) {
 if(Ob.GetType().IsGenericType && Ob is IList) {

      IList theList = (IList)Ob;            
      Array array = new object[theList.Count];
      theList.CopyTo(array, 0);
      Array.ForEach(array , Console.WriteLine);
  }
}
```